# Find the row/column reference of a variable containing a calculated maximum value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of percent change values. Each is associated with a stock ticker value in the same row, two columns over. I need to write VBA code that finds the minimum and maximum percent change value, then returns the min/max values themselves as well as the associated stock ticker value (a string) in the same row.

The below code returns the maximum percent change value and prints it to cell (2,15), no problem:

```
Sub minmax() 
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim dblMax As Double
  Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("L:L")
  dblMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(rng)
  Cells(2, 15).Value = dblMax
End Sub
```

I thought I could use the .Row method to retrieve the stock ticker value from two columns over by doing the following within the same sub:

```
targetVal = Cells(dblMax.Row, 10).Value
```

When I do this, it gives me an error that says "invalid qualifier". I have tried re-declaring dblMax as a long and as a Variant but that hasn't helped. I have also tried using the longer .Find method, and that gives me the invalid qualifier error as well.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: `Dim rowMax as Long: rowMax = Application.Match(dblMax, rng, 0)` gives you the row number where the max value is located.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you so much! This solved the issue.